# Use jQuery on elements, but not affect children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to automatically fix widows in the text of my site with the following jQuery. This is in WordPress, which is why I'm using no-conflict mode.

```
jQuery('p,h1,h2').not('a').each(function(){
    var string = jQuery(this).html();
    string = string.replace(/ ([^ ]*)$/,'&nbsp;$1');
    jQuery(this).html(string);
});
```

The problem is that this also affects the space between a and href in any links inside paragraphs, making it a href, which breaks the link. I tried adding .not('a') to keep this from running on links, but it doesn't help. I also tried 'p > a' thinking it would specify only children of p which also didn't work.

Is it possible to exclude just "a href" from this script so that it doesn't affect links?

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
$('p,h1,h2').each(function(){
    var string = $(this).html();
    if(!$(string).is('a')) {
        var string_out = string.replace(/ ([^ ]*)$/,'&nbsp;$1');
        $(this).html(string_out);
        console.log([string, string_out]);
   }
});
```

worked link : https://jsfiddle.net/mscdeveloper/k562v82w/